# Passing variable inside of function to a variable outside of function

Tags: python, function, variables

I am trying to set a new variable to reference a variable inside a function. My pseudo code goes like this:

```
def myfunction():
   a bunch of stuff that results in
   myvariable = "Some Text"
```

Further down the code I have this:

```
for something in somethinglist:
   if something == iteminsomethinglist:
       myfunction()
       mynewvariable1 = myvariable
   elif something == iteminsomethinglist:
       myfunction()
       mynewvariable2 = myvariable
   else:
       mynewvariable3 = myvariable
```

I keep getting an error message that says something like: **name 'myvariable' is not defined**

I guess I thought that if I called the function, it processes some stuff, I pass result into a variable and then reference that variable to a more unique variable, it would store it....but it's not.

**Edit:** I am attaching my code because it I wasn't clear enough in my first post. There is a variable within my function I wanted to reference outside of it (actually there are 2) I apologize for not making it clear enough. I though my original psuedo code proposed the question well enough. I also have a feeling that this might not be the best approach. Possible calling 2 functions would be more appropriate? My code is below:

```
def datetypedetector():

    rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)

    dateList = []

    for row in rows:
        dateList.append(row.getValue("DATE_OBSERVATION").strftime('%m-%d-%Y'))

    del row, rows

    newList = sorted(list(set(dateList)))

    dates = [datetime.strptime(d, "%m-%d-%Y") for d in newList]

    date_ints = set([d.toordinal() for d in dates])

    if len(date_ints) == 1:
        DTYPE = "Single Date"
        #print "Single Date"
    elif max(date_ints) - min(date_ints) == len(date_ints) - 1:
        DTYPE = "Range of Dates"
        #print "Range of Dates"
    else:
        DTYPE = "Multiple Dates"
        #print "Multiple Dates"

    fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for fc in fcList:

    if fc == "SO_SOIL_P" or fc == "AS_ECOSITE_P":
        datetypedetector()
        ssDate = newList
        print fc + " = " + str(ssDate)
        ssDatetype = DTYPE
        print ssDatetype

    elif fc == "VE_WEED_P":
        datetypedetector()
        vwDate = newList
        print fc + " = " + str(vwDate)
        vwDatetype = DTYPE
        print vwDatetype

    else: 
        datetypedetector()
        vrDate = newList
        print fc + " = " + str(vrDate)
        vrDatetype = DTYPE
        print vrDatetype
```

Comment: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/python-variable-scope-notes/

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto No, his code shouldn't work. Why are you saying that?

Comment: @Marcin: Never mind... I misunderstood the code... Sigh. I was basically thinking the whole thing was in one function, but I should have been more careful...

Comment: @Marcin, please saty away from my post if you can't be constructive.

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto thank you for suggesting a workaround

Comment: @MikeMacRae Please, stay away from SO if you are going to fill it with questions that could be answered by reading a tutorial.

Comment: @Marcin - It seems to me that this is the perfect site to ask a question like this.  See the [**What kind of questions can I ask here?**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) section of the FAQ.

Comment: @F.J: Note the alt text (`title` to be pedantic) for the downvote button: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". That seems like a perfect description of this question; in addition, it will only be of use to the OP, as anyone also so confused as to variable scopes is unlikely to find this question through searching.

Comment: @Marcin Please leave. I came here for help. You are not helping.

Comment: @MikeMacRae Do I owe you help? You are unwilling to even help yourself.

Comment: @Marcin - Just because it is trivial for you to find the answer doesn't mean that the OP didn't try.  Regardless of what you may think it is perfectly acceptable for people to ask questions here before they have mastered tutorials for the language.

Comment: @ Marcin I didn't specifically ask for your kind of help. Again, please leave.

Comment: @Marcin You completely fail to understand when your comments are unwelcome. I re-iterate for the third time. Please leave my posts.

Comment: @MikeMacRae You do not own these posts, and you cannot ban me from commenting. Meanwhile, you completely fail to understand why your question is not constructive.

Comment: @Marcin I do research my codes. I have spent countless hours in the past trying to understand all of my code. Today I am on a tight timeline and I needed a quick answer. I believe that is allowed and I am absolutely sure, I wouldn't be the first to have done that. This is where you fail to understand the situation behind a post on here and react out of your own impatience and obvious need of something better to do. I would suggest you go and hug someone today. It seems you need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written, `myvariable` is only defined within the scope of `myfunction`.
To make the value in that variable available outside of the function you can return it from the function:

```
def myfunction():
    myvariable = "Some Text"
    return myvariable
```

And then use it later like this:

```
for something in somethinglist:
    if something == iteminsomethinglist:
        mynewvariable1 = myfunction()
```

---

Edit:  new information added to question.

Your indentation seems slightly off, but that may just be copy-paste trouble.
I think what you want to do is something like this:

1. Call the `datetypedetector` function taking `fc` as an argument.
2. Return `DTYPE` from that function for later use.

So first change the function signature to:

```
def datetypedetector(fc):
                     ^^
```

And the final statement in `datetypedetector` to:

```
    return DTYPE
```

And then pass `fc` as an argument when you call it, and the final step is to get the `DTYPE` back from the function by assigning to it `datetypedetector`'s return value.

```
for fc in fcList:
    if fc == "SO_SOIL_P" or fc == "AS_ECOSITE_P":
        DTYPE = datetypedetector(fc)
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks Adam. This helped a lot!

Comment: Glad we could put you on the right track. Best of luck w/ the project.

Answer (score 1):

A much better way to organize the code would be to do something like this:

```
def myfunction():
   return "Some Text"

for something in somethinglist:
   if something == iteminsomethinglist:
       mynewvariable1 = myfunction()
   elif something == iteminsomethinglist:
       mynewvariable2 = myfunction()
   else:
       mynewvariable3 = myfunction()
```

Comment: Thank you for the added value Pearsonartphoto!